# Node.js API with express & mysql - Apply search parameter only if set

Tags: php, mysql, sql, node.js, express

My current query looks like this:

```
router.get('/search?', function(req, res, next) {
    var title = req.query.title;
    var active = req.query.active;
    var sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE title = ? AND active = ?"; 
    connection.query(sql, [title, active], function (error, results, fields) {
        res.json({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results});
    });
});
```

It works it I enter:

```
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?title=mr&active=1
```

But it doesn't work if one is not set:

```
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?title=mr

{"status":200,"error":null,"response":[]}
```

How can I make the query and return the desired string regardless if one or the other search parameter is set or not? So like:

```
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?title=mr
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?active=1 
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?title=mr&active=1
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?active=1&title=mr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to build your query dynamically according to the params set in the request:

```
router.get('/search?', function(req, res, next) {
    var sql = "SELECT * from users ";
    const existingParams = ["title", "active"].filter(field => req.query[field]);

    if (existingParams.length) {
        sql += " WHERE ";
        sql += existingParams.map(field => `${field} = ?`).join(" AND ");
    }

    connection.query(
        sql,
        existingParams.map(field => req.query[field]),
        function (error, results, fields) {
            res.json({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results});
        }
    );
});
```

this way if you want to handle more params you can just add them the "existingParams" statement

Comment: You have missed last condition  var sql = "SELECT * from users";
const existingParams = ["title", "active"].filter(field => req.query[field]);
if (existingParams.length !== 0)
    sql += ' WHERE ';

Comment: Unfortunately its not working properly ... I provided the results above.

Comment: Rahul is right. if (existingParams.length !== 0) sql += ' WHERE '; was missing ... but also existingParams should be in the .query() ... instead I need to defined them depending if available. The above is working. Not sure if that is the best way to do so though

Comment: yeah sorry for the different mistakes, i edited the answer